# C++ macros with variables without parentheses

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

In C++ one can do something like

```
#define my_happy_macro(x) do_something_with(x)
```

Or also

```
#define $(x) do_something_with(x)
```

What I would like to do, however, is something like

```
#define $x do_something_with(x)
```

So that when I write

```
$x;
```

in my code, the preprocessor substitutes it with

```
do_something_with(x);
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: No, and I pity the next person who's going to have to maintain this monstrosity.

Comment: Not possible. `$x` is a single token that incurs no special parsing rules; why would you want something like that anyway?

Comment: @0x499602D2: In standard C++, `$x` is not a single token. It's a sequence of two preprocessor tokens, `$` (which is a preprocessing token but not a valid token) followed by `x` (an identifier). Since `$` is not an identifier, the macro definition `#define $x do_something_with(x)` is invalid. gcc, as an extension, permits `$` in identifiers.

Comment: @KeithThompson `$` is not valid at all in standard C++ code (other than in string or char literals etc), so we can assume OP is using an extension where `$` is permitted in identifiers (e.g. as per C11 J.5.2) and so `$x` would be a single preprocessing token.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `$` is a valid *preprocessor token*. It becomes invalid if it survives past preprocessing. Your assumption is very likely correct, but it should be stated explicitly in any answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not something that the preprocessor can manage.

As an addendum to what others have said, it is really best to avoid heavy use of macros unless you really know what you are trying to do with them, and have a good reason not to simply create a function for the job.